# Escaping backslash in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, backslash

I'm trying to understand why the command below doesn't work (output is empty):

```
echo 'aaa\tbbb' | awk -F '\\t' '{print $2}'
```

I would expect the output to be 'bbb'.

Interestingly this works (output is 'bbb'):

```
echo 'aaa\tbbb' | awk -F 't' '{print $2}'
```

And this works as well (ouptut is 'tbbb'):

```
echo 'aaa\tbbb' | awk -F '\\' '{print $2}'
```

It looks as if `\\\t` is read as *backslash followed by tab* instead of *escaped backslash followed by t*.

Is there a proper way to write this command?

Comment: The second and third attempts *work* for the wrong reason.  You need to check what is being piped to `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `echo` to interpret backslash escapes.  Try:

```
$ echo -e 'aaa\tbbb' | awk -F '\t' '{print $2}'
bbb
```

`man echo` would tell:

```
   -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. In practice though my input is coming from a file, e.g. head myfile.txt | awk -F '\t' '{print $2}'. Is there a way to make it work in this case?

Comment: If the input file contains tab characters, then it should work.

Comment: The file contains multiple '\t' on each line (e.g. 'aaa\tbbb\tccc\tddd\n') but these are interpreted as backslashes followed by t, not as tabs, so the awk command (awk -F '\t' '{print $2}' myfile.txt) does not work.

Comment: Found the solution: while read -r line ; do echo -e $line | awk -F '\t' '{print $2}' ; done < myfile.txt